# Padding in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gtk

Given below is my ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

```
 VteTerminal,
    TerminalScreen {
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        -VteTerminal-inner-border: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
```

I was using the above code before to enable padding in my gnome-terminal. This doesn't seem to work anymore after a recent gtk update. How do I enable padding in the terminal now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem, I fixed it by simply replacing:

```
VteTerminal,
TerminalScreen {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -VteTerminal-inner-border: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

with

```
vte-terminal {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: I recently discovered, that terminals like **gnome-console** (kgx) written in GTK-4 are referring to `~/.config/gtk-4.0/gtk.css` to change the vte-padding since gnome-43.

Answer (score 1):

GTK 3.20 does not reveal internal widget names to CSS anymore. GNOME Terminal 3.20 doesn't assign "node names" yet, but in 3.21.x (git master) it uses `terminal-window`. Likewise, in VTE git master (not yet in 0.44), the terminal widget is `vte-terminal`.

Comment: So, I'll have to wait for the official updates then?